# How To Deploy Additional Kafka Broker (Docker Image)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have got Kafka working (using Docker image) on a single server where I have got Zookeeper + Kafka Broker on the same/one Server X.

If I need to additional broker on Server Y (for resiliency), do i need to deploy Kafka Broker on server Y and point to the same Zookeeper on Server X?

Or do i need to deploy Zookeeper on Server Y as well?  if so, how i get both Zookeepers discover each other ?

Comment: There's a cluster example in the Confluent Github repo for those images. Most people deploy clusters using kubernetes, though, rather than manually roll those images out

Comment: yes, but dont have support to use K8 atm ,so stuck with rolling/managing ourselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how i get both Zookeepers discover each other ?

You'd set the [`ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS`](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.2.1-post/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml#L12) variable to point at each ZK

> do i need to deploy Kafka Broker on server Y and point to the same Zookeeper on Server X?

For resiliency, yes. You would use [`KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT`](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.2.1-post/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml#L52) to point the brokers at the ZK cluster.

Note: `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` will need configured to return the external network address of both servers rather than only `localhost` or the Docker image service name for clients to work. Similarly, the inter-broker listener will need configured so that topic replication will work.

Note (2): You will want persistent volume mounts to preserve ZK and Kafka data from containers.